# Getting stuck at local optima in variational inference because of forced parameters dependence

Tags: optimization, variational-bayes

I am using stochastic variational inference for a model, where two of local variational parameters depend on each other. Regularly they are updated simultaneously, and part this update looks like something as below:

```
while true
    for i from 1 to #observations
        z1_new[i] = f(z2_old[i])
        z1_old[i] = z1_new[i]
        z2_new[i] = f(z1_old[i]) 
        z2_old[i] = z2_new[i]
    end
    //
    //update of other parameters
    //
    stop if a condition is met
end
```

However this dependence may force some values which z1 and z2 may not ever be able to escape from. Changing the simultaneous update to sequential as below although solves the problem for a case that I am working on:

```
while true
    for i from 1 to #observations
        z1_new[i] = f(z2_old[i])
    end
    z1_old = z1_new
    for i from 1 to #observations
        z2_new[i] = f(z1_old[i]) 
    end
    z2_old = z2_new
    //
    //update of other parameters
    //
    stop if a condition is met
end
```

As it allows the parameters to move around a bit more easily. I also change this order randomly so that the results are not order dependent. Is this approach acceptable, and is there anyway that this problem is addressed in the literature? More specifically, are there any references in the literature that address the inconvenient forced dependence between variational parameters that prevents escaping from a situation?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know your specific subject matter at all. But my general experience of iterative methods is that you tend to have something like `do {z1_new = f(z2_old);  z2_new = f(z1_old); z1_old = z1_new; z2_old = z2_new}} until(end condition reached)`? Your second code appears to be `z1_new = f(z2_old); z2_new = f(z1_new)`?

Comment: The two code snippets you posted are entirely equivalent. Splitting that into two loops doesn't change a thing.

Comment: So yes, I should edit with the old and new to make it clearer.